# Leer byte con System.in.read

Tags: java

Tengo este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int n = System.in.read();
            System.out.println(n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Si introduzco por teclado á devuelve el 195. ¿Por qué?
Con í, ó, ú devuelve lo mismo. Pero, sin embargo, para ¬ devuelve 194 que tampoco corresponde con su tabla Unicode.

Hasta donde yo sé, read tendría que devolver un byte (sólo se podría representar los primeros 128 caracteres) y, además, el á corresponde con el Unicode 225.

Así, si funcionaría:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
int n = isr.read();
```

Pero trato de entender por qué el 195.

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: en mi maquina con `á` obtengo `225` si lo ejecuto desde el IDE lo que coincide con UTF-8 y `160` desde `cmd.exe` lo cual tambien coincide con el codepage 850

Comment: a mí desde OSX y en Linux con distintos IDEs, tanto en consola como en el IDE, con á obtengo 195.

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero es aclarar que el rango de valores de un byte es [-128, 127], por lo que el número positivo mayor que se puede manejar con un byte es 127. Esto ocurre porque el octavo bit (el primero de izquierda a derecha) se utiliza para indicar el signo.

Lo anterior hace imposible representar más de esa cantidad de caracteres con un solo byte. Por tal motivo en java utiliza el formato UTF-16 en sus caracteres, representando cada uno con 2 bytes (a partir de Java 9 se introdujo una optimización en la forma de representar los `String` la cual permite no siempre utilizar 2 bytes por caracter si no es necesario). Para lograr representar un caracter UTF-16 de este modo, se realiza un pequeño algoritmo sobre el código del caracter, el cual mostramos a continuación.

Un ejemplo con la á:

- Su código es 225 en decimal (mayor que 127, hay que dividirlo), y en binario 0000-0000-1110-0001 (utilizando 2 bytes).
- Se descartan los primeros 5 bits (de izquierda a derecha) se ignoran porque no son necesarios, quedando 000-1110-0001
- Los 5 primeros bits se superponen en las equis de 110x-xxxx. Con esto obtenemos nuestro primer byte 1100-0011, que en decimal es 195.
- Los 6 bits restantes se superponen en las equis de 10xx-xxxx. Con esto obtenemos nuestro segundo byte 1010-0001, que en decimal es 161.

Por lo que la representación de la á sería [195 161].

Por esto es que al leer un byte con el método `System.in.read()`, solo lees el primer byte de la representación de la á, el cual es 195.

Si lo que deseas es leer caracteres debes utilizar un `Scanner`, de la siguiente forma.

```
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String cadena = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(cadena);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Notar que `Scanner` cuenta con un método para leer solo un caracter.

Con el método `InputStreamReader.read()` si te funciona porque te este retorna un `int` que tiene una capacidad de 4 bytes, que es superior a los 2 bytes del caracter que introduces.

Comment: De dónde sale el 110x-xxxx y el 10xx-xxxx. Tenemos 0000 0000 1110 0001. quitamos los primeros 5 bits con lo cual 000 1110 0001 el 110 y lo siguiente no lo entiendo. Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Son números fijos que se utilizan en el algoritmo.